# JQuery ajax form submit for return file giving undefined error response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Due to various issues with security of file manipulation, I am forced to submit the request via Ajax post method call. The server side URL receives this and gives out a pdf file as response. Server side code in java servlet is as below.

```
            ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + outFile);
        //create the pdf file
        response.flushBuffer();
```

On the client side, the javascript code is sending call to a POST which calls the above code via doPost. When the form is submitted through form.submit(), the file gets downloaded nicely as pdf file. When trying through Ajax call, it is giving me undefined response under error section. Client side code as below.

```
    var formData = new FormData();
//Fill formData with fields and files
    console.log('Posting form from ajax');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/createPdf",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'blob'
        },
        success: function (response, status, xhr) {
            console.log('Processing response');
            download(response, "merged.pdf", "application/pdf" );

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) 
        { 
            var err = xhr.responseText; 
            alert(err); 
        }
```

In the above, it is not going under success response. It is going under error and alerting as undefined. What am I doing wrong here. My jquery version is 1.8.0.min.js if that matters. download function refers to http://danml.com/download.html but I have tried the other snippets too but it doesn't even come to success.

Under Inspection tools, I see success request and blob data in response, but it takes about 10-15 seconds for the blob data to show under Network in browser

Please help. I have been at it all evening and can't seem to figure out undefined response.

Comment: Why don't you try logging the other two arguments passed to your `error` callback (ie `console.error(status, error)`)? Who knows, they could be useful.

Comment: try to find if there is problem in serverside if any so put System.out.print to find out the server side logging.

Comment: @RahulDudharejiya OP says _"Under Inspection tools, I see success request and blob data in response"_ so presumably that isn't a problem

Comment: if your response is completely perfect then it should logging into success so there must be some problem in server side, try to debug at server side

Comment: @RahulDudharejiya, like Phil mentioned, if I try through normal form.submit() it gets downloaded from same server side without any issues, so not an issue there.

Comment: @Phil, alerting all three gives undefined for err, error for status and for error object, the message as "InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'responseXML' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'document' (was 'blob')."

Comment: A quick search around suggests jQuery does not handle binary downloads very well. Most suggestions recommend `XMLHttpRequest` though these days I'd try `fetch` first

Comment: @Phil, you are awesome and pointed me in the right direction. I used normal XMLHttpRequest and it worked like a charm. I wanted to use jQuery for cross browser compatibility but didn't realize that it would be the issue. Does it have to do with the jQuery version 1.8 though, if so, I can change the version even though I don't know if it would break something else. Is the cross browser compatibility stated on the web for jQuery usage overrated.

Comment: @Phil, I am unable to accept your answer as a comment, if you can post as an answer, I will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

For ajax download you should dynamic add link, trigger click and then delete.

```
var formData = new FormData();
//Fill formData with fields and files
    console.log('Posting form from ajax');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/createPdf",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'blob'
        },
        success: function (response, status, xhr) {
             var a = document.createElement('a');
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'myfile.pdf';
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) 
        { 
            var err = xhr.responseText; 
            alert(err); 
        }
```

Comment: I had this normal flow instead of download.js too, but the issue is not dynamic link and clicking, it does not even enter the success block after Ajax response. It goes to error block and the alert shows as undefined.

Answer (score -1):

You mentioned in your form.submit () it works without any issue. What type are you using, POST or GET? I World try to change it in your ajax request. I'm no java pro but maybe your Servlet only reacts to GET requests. When I worked with Ajax and Servlets I used http Servlet where I overwrote the doGet method.

Comment: I have used POST method and Servlet is implementing the doPost method. form.submit() is using post as form is defined with method="post"